# Como colapsar un data frame con R

Tags: r

Hola buenas estoy tratando de colapsar un data frame q tengo con R, la idea es que tengo 3 variables: sitio, especie, biomasa. Para cada sitio tengo una lista de especies donde se suele repetir varias veces las mismas especies en los sitios con biomasas, y quiero q me salga para cada sitio solo una vez cada especie, con la suma de las abundancias si ha salido mas de una vez en ese sitio. 
Estaba utilizando el paquete dplyr, y tratando de hacerlo con summarise(group_by), pero solo consigo q me colapse la lista de todas las especies que salen en total en todos los sitios juntos y su biomasa total de todos los sitios juntos, no separado por cada sitio observado. Pero me serviría hacerlo de cualquier manera en R.
Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos,
Incluir un ejemplo de los datos acelera el proceso. Puede ser codigo que genere los datos o si lo copias del portapapeles. Acá una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) en ingles sobre el tema.
Supongamos datos como estos:

```
set.seed(3)
datos <- data.frame(sitio=paste0("sitio",sample(3,10,replace=TRUE)),
                    especie=paste0("e",sample(4,10,replace=10)),
                    biomasa=round(rnorm(10,20),0))

    sitio      especie   biomasa
    1  sitio3      e3      18
    2  sitio3      e1      21
    3  sitio2      e4      20
    4  sitio3      e4      21
    5  sitio2      e2      21
    6  sitio1      e4      19
    7  sitio1      e1      20
    8  sitio1      e1      18
    9  sitio3      e1      20
    10 sitio1      e4      20
```

La respuesta de Rubén es excelente:

```
 datos %>% group_by(sitio, especie) %>% summarise(biomasa = sum(biomasa))

   sitio especie biomasa
  (fctr)  (fctr)   (dbl)
1 sitio1      e1      38
2 sitio1      e4      39
3 sitio2      e2      21
4 sitio2      e4      20
5 sitio3      e1      41
6 sitio3      e3      18
7 sitio3      e4      21
```

Sin embargo yo propongo el uso de data.table como alternativa, que es ligeramente mas rapida y a mi me parece mas sencilla:

```
 library(data.table)
 datos <- as.data.table(datos)
 datos[,sum(biomasa), by=c("especie","sitio")]
    especie  sitio V1
 1:      e3 sitio3 18
 2:      e1 sitio3 41
 3:      e4 sitio2 20
 4:      e4 sitio3 21
 5:      e2 sitio2 21
 6:      e4 sitio1 39
 7:      e1 sitio1 38
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías dar más detalles del problema (p.e. incluir algo de código).

Si utilizas el paquete dplyr ten en cuenta que puedes agrupar por más de una variable. Ejemplo:

```
datos %>% group_by(sitio, especie) %>% summarise(biomasa = sum(biomasa))
```

Espero que te sirva...